# React Native ble advertiser in background

Tags: react-native, bluetooth-lowenergy, react-native-ios, background-process

I am trying to implement ble advertiser (https://github.com/vitorpamplona/react-native-ble-advertiser). It is working fine in android, but for iOS there is a problem that when the app is in background or screen is locked, scanning and broadcasting stopped. Implemented the example added in library (https://github.com/vitorpamplona/react-native-ble-advertiser/tree/master/example).

Also tried the https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-background-fetch as suggested in library but no success. Even with background fetch it stopped working on foreground.

any lead!!!